# mod_rewrite - from sub domain to file in document root

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, vhosts

I have an incoming url like this:

```
http://api.example.com/get/user/12345/posts?limit=10&offset=0&order=desc&record=type,date
```

and I need it to be rewritten to (pseudo code)

```
[DocumentRoot]/dispatch.php?url=http://api.example.com/get/user/12345/posts?limit=10&offset=0&order=desc&record=type,date
```

Totally new to it, so best case you could give me the whole **=VirtualHost=** block.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ [DocumentRoot]/dispatch.php/$1/$2/$3/$4 [L,QSA]
```

mh that for the htaccess file (mod rewrite), you can as far as i know add it directly to your vhost (but read how to do that)